# JavaFX: resize GridPane with window resizing

Tags: java, javafx

I have a `GridPane` object in my scene. I want to be able to resize the window and have the pane resized with it. I also want to put a `VBox` next to my pane.

So far I've managed to produced either a completely resizable `GridPane` or an `AnchorPane` that contains both the `GridPane` and the `VBox` objects but when I resize the window the pane does not resize along with it.

Here's the FXML with `AnchorPane`:

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="750.0" prefWidth="1000.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="%controllername%">
    <children>
        <GridPane layoutX="50" layoutY="25" maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="700" prefWidth="700">
            <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" minWidth="10.0" percentWidth="33.3" prefWidth="100.0" />
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            </columnConstraints>
            <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" percentHeight="33.3" prefHeight="100.0" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="100.0" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="100.0" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
            </rowConstraints>
            <children>
                <Button maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#boardButtonAction" />
                <Button maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#boardButtonAction" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                <Button maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#boardButtonAction" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                <Button maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#boardButtonAction" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                <Button maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#boardButtonAction" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                <Button maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#boardButtonAction" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                <Button maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#boardButtonAction" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
                <Button maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#boardButtonAction" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                <Button maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#boardButtonAction" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            </children>
        </GridPane>
      <VBox layoutX="813.0" layoutY="266.0" prefHeight="218.0" prefWidth="137.0">
          <children>
              <Button maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false"  />
              <Button maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false"  />
              <Button maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" />
          </children>
      </VBox>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

The version with just the `GridPane` is basically the `GridPane` code used in the `AnchorPane` version but with `xmlns` and `fx:controller` attributes.

How do I make a scene which would feature resizable `GridPane` and `VBox` next to each other?

Comment: Your `GridPane` doesn't resize since you don't use any constraints that make the `AnchorPane` layout it's children in a different way than `Pane` which just resizes the children to their preffered sizes. You need to replace `layoutX="813.0" prefHeight="218.0"` with something like `AnchorPane.leftAnchor="813" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0"` (and proceede accordingly for horizontal constraints...). The `HBox` solution is much better though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the easiest way to do this is to create an HBox and add the GridPane and the VBox to it. Set the "fillHeight" property to true on the HBox. The "fillWidth" properties on the GridPane and VBox should be set to true, and their HGrow properties set to "always," (or "sometimes"). The HBox should resize with the window it's in, while the GridPane and VBox should expand to divide the available space between them.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>


<HBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <GridPane style="-fx-border-color: black;" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
      </GridPane>
      <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" style="-fx-border-color: red;" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
   </children>
</HBox>
```